# Как отцентрировать по экрану модальное окно?

Tags: окно, css

Всем здравствуйте!
Есть скрипт модального окна, с помощью которого будут открываться любое кол-во окон на странице. Размеры окон будут разные.
Помогите, пожалуйста, отцентрировать его по вертикали и горизонтали экрана.
Сам скрипт: http://jsfiddle.net/LADYX/3ctvrz8d/
Очень буду благодарен за помощь! Спасибо.

Comment: @LADYX, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вам по вертикали тоже по центру или с небольшим отступом сверху?

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/3ctvrz8d/4/)

Comment: Отличия:

 * В первом случае, если на странице будет много контента, то до модального окна, возможно, придётся скроллить. Такой вариант подойдёт для промо-страницы. В общем, любой дизайн с фиксированной вертикалью.
 * С небольшим отступом - универсальный вариант.

@LADYX, меняйте

    .modal_div {
        ...
        margin: 30px auto;    
    }

и будет вам счастье.